# Faulty ArcGIS Address Locator

Tags: arcgis-online, address, arcgis-runtime, geocoding

We are using a product that makes use of ArcGIS Runtime Engine 10.2. In attempting to find a particular address using the World Geocode Service (ArcGIS Online), I'm receiving nonsensical results:

Looking up: 100 Woodside Cr NW, Airdrie /
Result:
(1) 100 Woodside Cres NW, Airdrie, Alberta, T4B -- 87%
(2) 100 Woodside Cir NW, Airdrie, Alberta, T4B -- 100%

Why does the locator return a lower match score percentage for the "correct" street type and assign a higher match score percentage to an "incorrect" street type?

I can tell you from the outset, that the street data I'm using comes from a GIS vendor that has no intention of altering the way they designate their street types: Street types will always be 2 characters.

Comment: This is an issue to discuss with Esri. All you can get here is speculation.  I would point out that the "correct" USPS abbreviation for Circle is "Cir" and for Cresent is "Cres". "Cr" is at least the first two characters of "Cres"

Comment: Thanks @Vince. I am not surprised that speculation is all I might receive on this site, given my question does point to an issue with ESRI's own Locator algorithm. I just wanted to cover my bases.

Comment: I think you might need to provide some simpler steps on how to replicate, ideally just using URL calls using the parameters you are specifying.  For example, if I hit it with this [standard request](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=100%20Woodside%20Cr%20NW,%20Airdrie&category=&outFields=*&forStorage=false&f=pjson), I get the correct result


If you edit your question to include that info, I think we can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would be isolating the issue with the World Geocode Service first.

When I pass your string over to the findAddressCandidates method on the World Geocode Service with no other parameters

[findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=**100 Woodside Cr NW, Airdrie**](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=100%20Woodside%20Cr%20NW,%20Airdrie&outFields=*&forStorage=false&f=pjson)

The 1st correct result returned:

**address: "100 Woodside Cir NW, Airdrie, Alberta, T4B",

score: 100**

And I think that is what you were expecting?
Therefore I would be inspecting the request that is being fired from your Product.  This could have whatever logic they decided to include into the app to perhaps make use of additional GeoCode Service parameters (e.g. limit results with bounding box, proximity bias, append a country code into the request, etc).

If it is an Esri product and you have no option to configure, then let them know.  If it is a partner product, let them know.

If you can access the Runtime Code that makes the geocode request, include that, along with some information on the requests being made from the app into your original question.